# How to add chat feature in a react native application that updates chat instantly if the message arrives from opposite side?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have implemented a chat feature in my application, but the issue I am facing is the screen does not refresh automatically if the user gets a message.

I looked for several options on the internet, but all I could find is paid services or using firebase.

Is there any free option to implement it without using firebase?

I want to refresh my chat screen instantly the message is received from the other side.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase and React but you can achieve it through a Websocket. It provides a persistent connection between a client and server. Check out Pusher.com and then you can browse some tutorials on how to implement it with your app. Hope this helps. https://pusher.com/

Comment: pusher.com is a paid service I guess?

Comment: firebase is your best free option

Comment: But the problem is I have integrated my whole authentication flow with services and now shifting to firebase would be a big deal